# find available time slots nodejs

Tags: node.js, timeslots

I have an array of employees that contains time slots of their meetings

```
[ {"id": 1, "name": "John", "meeting": [{"Time_Start": "1/3/2015 12:30:00 PM", 
"Time_End": "1/3/2015 13:30:00 PM"}]},
{"id": 2, "name": "Peter", "meeting": [{"Time_Start": "1/5/2015 7:00:00 AM", 
"Time_End": "1/5/2015 8:00:00 AM"}]}]
```

Considering that a work day is from 8 to 17.00. How can I find the available time slots for a meeting with specific duration for a day? Every meeeting starts on a half or whole hour.

Comment: Enumerate the time slots in a day then remove those that overlap with any existing meetings.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: have you found any solution? I'm facing this right now, and have no ideal how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You could use a boolean array where every index in the array represents a half an hour of the time slot during the day. And you could store these array's in an object where the day format is the key.